# Cannot install numpy, pip or PILLOW from conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, debian, raspberry-pi4

I am using a Raspberry Pi to install coral USB following this link https://github.com/google-coral/tflite/tree/master/python/examples/classification. where i use the prompt command  ./install_requirements.sh for machine learning inferencing and when i try to run ./install_requires.sh command it gives me the error:

```
/home/pi/miniconda3/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

The command is executed from the path:

```
~/google-coral/tflite/python/examples/classification
```

However when i do: pip --version i get:

```
pip 21.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

I also tried running the inference code

```
python3 classify_image.py \
  --model models/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite \
  --labels models/inat_bird_labels.txt \
  --input images/parrot.jpg
```

It returns the following error:

```
  File "classify_image.py", line 33, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Why is it giving me these errors even though i already have python and pip installed?

Comment: create a separate virtual enviroment and install necessary required packages and run your script from there.

Comment: I created a new environment and ran ./install_requires.sh and it gave:      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9z__p15v/numpy/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Python version >= 3.7 required.")
I tried installing python 3.9 as in this link: https://www.ramoonus.nl/2020/10/06/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-raspberry-pi/, however after installing many times over it still says i have Python 3.4 after many tries. My brain cells just burned out :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two python interpreters.

```
 /home/pi/miniconda3/bin/python3 
 /usr/local/lib/python3.7
```

you could try `conda install pip` to install pip for `/home/pi/miniconda3/bin/python3`, then the command `./install_requirements.sh` will work.

Since you haven't install requirement packages, you couldn't find module

```
PIL(ImportError: No module named 'PIL')
```

Comment: I tried doing conda install using the environment that is on the path /home/pi/miniconda3/bin/python3 and i got: Error: Missing write permissions in: /home/pi/miniconda3